# Jquery Validation Plugin: When the form just become valid, the first submit click do not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a Jquery Validation Plugin problem:

When the form just become valid (the error message is just gone), the first submit click do not work, I need to click again to make it work properly.
I suppose when the form is just become valid it is still in a "not submitable" mode.
Please is there anyway to make it work from the first click after validated ??
Thank you very much !

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

      <div class="row-fluid" id="top">
          <!--top-->
      </div>

      <div class="row-fluid">
       <form id="signInForm">
             <label class="control-label" for="usermail">e-mail</label>
             <input type="text" id="usermail" name="usermail">
             <span class="errMsg">*</span>

             <label class="control-label" for="pass">Password</label>
             <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass">
             <span class="errMsg">*</span>

             <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
       </form>                   
      </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#signInForm').validate({ 
                                   debug: false,
                       rules: { usermail:{required:true,email:true,remote:"Ajax_isSigned.php"},
                                    pass:"required"
                               },
                    messages: { usermail:{required:"Required !",email:"wrong format",remote:"mail never been registered"},
                                    pass:"Required !"
                               },
               submitHandler: function(){submitForm()}
                           })// End of validate()

}); // End of  $(document).ready

function submitForm(){
$("#signInForm").submit(function(event) {

                               $.ajax({
                                      type: "POST",
                                       url: "Ajax_Login2.php",
                                      data: $(this).serialize(),
                                   success: function(html){ if(html=='success'){;$('#top').text('OK')}}
                                      });// end of $.ajax
                                      return false;
                                        });
}
</script>                                     
</body>
</html>
```

OK, This is a final and tested working code after all the helps:

```
$('#signInForm').validate({ 
                       debug: false,
                errorElement:"span",
                  errorClass:"errMsg",
                   onfocusout: function () {$('#usermail').valid();}, // only check on focusout, NOT onChange.
                      onkeyup: function () {$('#pass').valid()}, // check on onChange.            
                submitHandler: function(){submitForm();return false;
                               },
                        rules: {
                                  usermail:{required:true,email:true,remote:"Ajax_isSigned.php"},
                                  pass:"required"
                               },

                    messages: {
                                 usermail:{required:"Required !",email:"wrong format",remote:"mail never been registered"},
                                 pass:"Required !"
                               }


                        })// End of validate()

function submitForm(){

                             $.ajax({
                                      type: "POST",
                                      url: "Ajax_Login.php",
                                      data: $('#signInForm').serialize(),
                       success: function(html){
                                              if(html=='success'){$('#top').append('OK<br>')}
                                              if(html=='fail'){$('#top').append('NG<br>')}
                                               }
                                      });// end of $.ajax


                       }// end of submitForm()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [jQuery Validate documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/):

> `submitHandler` (default: native form submit):
>
> Type: Function()
>
> Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets
>   the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. **The right
>   place to submit a form via Ajax after it validated**.

In other words, do not create another submit handler function when one is already built into the plugin and it's designed for this exact scenario.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#signInForm').validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            usermail: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: "Ajax_isSigned.php"
            },
            pass: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            usermail: {
                required: "Required !",
                email: "wrong format",
                remote: "mail never been registered"
            },
            pass: "Required !"
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Ajax_Login2.php",
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (html) {
                    if (html == 'success') {
                        $('#top').text('OK')
                    }
                }
            }); // end of $.ajax
            return false;
        }
    }) // End of validate()

}); // End of  $(document).ready
```

---

**EDIT:**

For my solution to work, you'll need to fix the syntax error with the `success` callback of your `ajax` code...

```
                success: function (html) {
                    if (html == 'success') {;  // <--- remove this semicolon
                        $('#top').text('OK')
                    }
                }
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/3CpBg/**

Comment: Hi Sparky,
Thanks for the answer, the above turned out to execute native form submit to the page itself.

Comment: @RayCLin, it will not do the native form submit unless there is a syntax error within the options or `return false` was left out of the `submitHandler`.

Comment: @RayCLin, See the edit on my answer.  You had a syntax error (stray semicolon) breaking your `ajax`.  Also see my working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3CpBg/

Comment: Thank you Sparky, 
it helps a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Call `$("#signInForm").valid()` in your `submitForm()` function prior to calling  `$("#signInForm").submit()`.  Should clear that problem right up.

Comment: Or get rid of the `.submit()` handler function since one is already built into the plugin.